# How can I make a class active on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that changes the background color on hover and this works fine. However, What I need to do is keep the hover function but also make the the class active on a click event.

I am having trouble finding a solution for this and would be grateful for any assistance. Thanks

PS: If it helps, I have bootstrap available.

```
$(function() {
  $(".SentmsgHdr").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f1f0ee");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fcfaf7");
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.SentmsgHdr', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    var sentid = $(this).find(".Sentdynid");
    var id = sentid.attr("id");

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "/domain/admin/Sentmsg.php",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function(data) {
          var date = new Date(data.date);
          var newDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear() + '  '+ date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() +  ':' + date.getSeconds() +'PM';

        $('#Sentdiv').html(
          '<div style="float: left;"><img src="/domain/admin/images/contact.png"></div>' + 
          '<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">' + data.from + 
          '<br />' + 
          '<span style="font-size: 13px; margin-top: 30px;">' + 'Ticket#: ' + 
          '<span id="Sentticket" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: red;">' + data.ticket + 
          '</span>' + 
          '</span>' +
          '<span style="font-size: 13px; display: block;">' + 'Subject: ' + '<span id="subject" style="font-size: 13px; color: black; font-weight: normal;">' + data.subject + '</span>' + 
          '</span>' + 
          '<span style="font-size: 13px; display: block;">' + 'Date: '+ '<span id="subject" style="font-size: 13px; color: black; font-weight: normal;">' + newDate + '</span>' +  
          '</span>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div style="width: 79%; margin-top: 20px; float: right; clear: both; font-size: 16px;">' + 
          '<hr style="border: 0.1em solid #ccc7c0; margin-top: -10px;">' + data.message + 
          '</div>' +
          '</div>'
          );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: try adding a class on click event and add desired CSS Properties to that class. Also, You don`t need to add a jquery function to add background to the element on hover. You can use CSS like .SentmsgHdr:hover {background-color: #f1f0ee}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some css class to active alement to separeate styles from hover to active.

Here's a simple example.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(ev) {
  $('.btn.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
nav a {
display: block;
padding: 2rem ;
font-size: 1.1rem;
background-color:#ccc;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
border: solid 1px #fff;
}
nav a:hover {
background-color:green;
color: #fff;
}

nav a.active {
background-color: blue;
color: #fff;
}
nav a.active:hover {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="btn">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">three</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Working. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is with CSS, not JavaScript, except for the click which should add a class. Here's an example, see comments:

```js
// I haven't disallowed repeated clicks here, but they'll be no-ops.
// If you want to disallow them, make the selector ".SentmsgHdr:not(.clicked)".
$(document).on("click", ".SentmsgHdr", function() {
  // Obviously the .text(...) part of this is just for this demo,
  // you probably just want the class part
  $(this).addClass("clicked").text("I have the class and have been clicked");
});
```

```css
/* Defines the color for them when not hovered */
.SentmsgHdr {
  background-color: #fcfaf7;
}
/* Defines the color for them when hovered */
.SentmsgHdr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f0ee;
}
/* Defines the color for them when they've been clicked */
.SentmsgHdr.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>I don't have the class</div>
<div class="SentmsgHdr">I have the class, click me</div>
<div>I don't have the class</div>
<div class="SentmsgHdr">I have the class, click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;

or you can delete `active:hover` from css and just edit `.SentmsgHdr:hover` class with background `!important`

```js
$(function() {
  /*
  $(".SentmsgHdr").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fcfaf7");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f1f0ee");
  });
  */
});

$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.SentmsgHdr', function() {
    //$(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.SentmsgHdr{
background-color: #fcfaf7;
}

.SentmsgHdr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f0ee;
}
.SentmsgHdr.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.SentmsgHdr.active:hover {
  background-color: #f1f0ee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="SentmsgHdr" >Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, it does nothing. I ameded my css with your code and added the jquery line and also removed the jquery hover function and nothing happens when i hover or click. thanks

Comment: It got a bit further this time. i added !important to hover and active and it works as expected. However, it is keeping the old active class hen i click the next link. Just keeps adding. I need to remove the class? Thanks

Comment: Did you add class active on click event to the button and delete the line `$(this).css('background', 'yellow');` . 
If you have any other active class you should rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Your main Problem is, that the hover styles INSTANTLY overwrite your click event styles. The solutions given by the others here should solve your Problem, because if you use a class on the click event instead of css, the hover styles will not overwrite your click event styles.